# AWS Sagemaker Endpoint inference "async-invocations" endpoint does not log of my log / print statements

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-sagemaker, endpoint

I've exposed a Sagemaker `async-invocations` endpoint using Python and Flask as explained [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_runtime_InvokeEndpointAsync.html). When I invoke the endpoint it gets triggered with correct inputs sent from the invocation and I can see that in the application logs in Cloudwatch, BUT I dont see my `print` statements that I've written inside the Flask endpoint's function created for `async-invocations`.

Also, since asyn-invocations accept S3 URI in `InputLocation`, and I've not written anything as such to download and read the input file from `InputLocation`, I am surprised how it is being read. Or is this managed automatically by AWS.

Comment: Do you see these logging statements in your CloudWatch logs? With SageMaker logs are meant to be reflected there for Inference.